WireMock scenario to store data across requests
Using WireMock 3.3.1 but can upgrade if new features are available to achieve my goal.
I need to store the value received with a request and reuse it in a subsequent request (to define a dynamic response).
I'm using WireMock Scenarios as follows
First call sets the cachedRefNum
{
"mappings": [
    {
        "scenarioName": "Cache Ref Number",
        "requiredScenarioState": "Started",
        "newScenarioState": "Cached",
        "request": {
            "method": "POST",
            "urlPath": "/firstcall"
        },
        "response": {
            "status": 200,
            "body": "{\"message\": \"Cached {{jsonPath request.body '$.d.refNum'}}\"}",
            "transformers": ["response-template"],
            "transformerParameters": {
                "cachedRefNum": "{{jsonPath request.body '$.d.refNum'}}"
            }
        }
    },

Second call uses cachedRefNum:
{
"mappings": [
    {
        "scenarioName": "Cache Ref Number",
        "requiredScenarioState": "Cached",
        "request": {
            "method": "GET",
            "urlPathPattern": "/secondcall"
        },
        "response": {
            "status": 200,
            "body": "{\"cachedRefNum\": \"{{lookup 'cachedRefNum'}}\"}",
            "transformers": ["response-template"],
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        }

When I perform my first call (POST) with following payload:
{
  "d": {
    "Lnehm": "1"
  }
}

I get the expected response:
{"message": "Cached 1"}

but with the second call (GET) the response is:
{
   "cachedRefNum": "cachedRefNum"
}

The way I see it either the cachedRefNum is not stored or the lookup cannot find it.
Any suggestion?

To do what you're attempting here you need the stateful extension.
You would do something like this to store a value from a request:

{
  "request": { ... },
  "response": { ... },
  "serveEventListeners": [
    {
      "name": "recordState",
      "parameters": {
        "context": "global",
        "state": {
          "cachedRefNum": "{{jsonPath request.body '$.d.refNum'}}"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

Then use it in your second response:
"body": "{\"cachedRefNum\": \"{{state context='global' property='cachedRefNum' default='0'}}\"}",

It may also be worth checking out WireMock Cloud's advanced state feature, which can make working with stateful flows quite a bit easier than with the OSS library.

Thanks, that's interesting, but I'm struggling registering the extension: it all works fine until I send the second request and I get an error similar to "HandlebarsException: could not find helper: 'state'" (I'm running the standalone version in my localhost).
Anyway I achieved something similar although in a less flexible way by using the scenario state to understand in the second call what was the result of the first one.
Not as powerful, but with few values does the job

Is the extension showing as loaded in the info printed to the console at startup?

No, it isn't. I also tried adding the wiremock-state-extension-standalone jar in classpath but in this case I always get a MissingResourceException and WireMock doesn't event start.

Have you tried upgrading to the latest version?

Went as far as version 3.7.0 (extension 0.8.0), same result.
